# How to move a UIImage 100px to the right only

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

In Xamarin iOS, how can I simply move an image to the right 100px from its current location?  I know that I am suppose to use Bounds, but I can't get the intenseness to really provide anything helpful.  I have googled it and there isn't much that I can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean an `UIImageView`, you can use the `Offset(dx,dy)` method on its `Frame` property. If your `UIImageView` is called `imageView`:

```
var frame = imageView.Frame;
frame.Offset(100,0); // offset 100px horizontal, 0 px vertical
imageView.Frame = frame; // set the frame of the image to the new position.
```

Note that you *must* take the frame object into a seperate variable. That is, `imageView.Frame.Offset(100,0)` will not work.

Comment: It didn't move the image at all.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? I have a tiny repro here with this code that works as expected.

Comment: Could it be that my code in my ViewDidLoad() is going first?

Comment: var frame = this.imgPin.Frame;

            Console.WriteLine("A: " + frame.Left.ToString());

            frame.Offset(100,200); // offset 100px horizontal, 0 px vertical
            this.imgPin.Frame = frame; // set the frame of the image to the new position.

            Console.WriteLine("B: " + frame.Left.ToString());

Comment: Even trying this and nothing: 
            this.imgPin.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, 10, 10, 10);

Comment: Dropbox repro: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0jrz8bhwa9egqin/stackoverflow-27853090_how-to-move-a-uiimage-100px-to-the-right-only.zip?dl=0

Note the strange behaviour that occurs if you uncomment the label line. There could be something in your code triggering the same thing.